# How to do without delete_if for Active Record?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, arrays, activerecord

When I do:

```
apartments = Apartment.where(apart_params).delete_if{|x| x.floor == x.max_floor }
```

Ruby's array method `delete_if` on Active record Relation object results in

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `delete_if' for #<Apartment::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00000006d84ea0>
Did you mean?  delete
               delete_all):
```

I don't understand why it happens - this object seems to respond like a plain array...

Is there any smarter alternative except using plain each do block?

Maybe you can give an advise on making smart SQL (postgres) query to reject those apartments which are on the last floor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relation can be converted to an array and then `delete_if` can be called:

```
Apartment.where(apart_params).to_a.delete_if {|x| x.floor == x.max_floor }
```

About a smarter way, it depends if the `floor` and `max_floor` methods are columns. If so, then:

```
Apartment.where(apart_params).where.not("floor = max_floor")
```

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks!

Comment: Be warned, this will delete the record from the database.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest switching your `apartments` assignment to the following:

`apartments = Apartment.where(apart_params).map{|x| x.floor == x.max_floor ? x.delete : x }`

Answer (score 2):

Even if the `Apartment.where(apart_params)` looks like a Array object, it isn't! As the error says, it returns a ActiveRecordRelation, that is not a Array. So, if you want to use array methods on a ActiveRecordRelation, you have to convert your object to a array with `to_a`

```
apartments = Apartment.where(apart_params).to_a.delete_if{|x| x.floor == x.max_floor }
```

Comment: I wish I could put a tick on two answers... Thank you!